# Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, computer-building

I've recently started building a new computer from scratch and I was wondering if there was a way around the $100 drop on a windows 10 operating system.

I have a free copy of windows 8.1 from Microsoft Dreamspark. I was just curious to know if i install Windows 8.1 on my newly built system, would i be able to upgrade to windows 10 for free or should i just not waste my time and buy windows 10?

Comment: If you can get Windows 10 for free why would you purchase it?  "Would I be able to upgrade to windows 10 for free" - What has your research shown?

Comment: I'm sure if that would work or not.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of articles on the free offer to Windows 10, it's not clear, what wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Windows 10 upgrade for free if you are able to activate your current Windows 8.1 installation.

Once it's activated Windows update will automatically show Windows 10 upgrade notification.

All this for free.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can upgrade to Windows 10 for free if your current Windows 8.1 is pro or home version. Microsoft's free Windows 10 upgrade offer officially expires on July 29, 2016.  Go to install all the available updates from Windows Update, and you will get the upgrade notification. If you don't like Windows 10, you have 30 days to go back to your previous version of Windows.

Comment: All versions (except enterprise) of Windows 8.1 is eligible for the offer....

Comment: Windows 8.1 only has 3 version: basic, pro and enterprise.

Comment: there is Single Version, Professional /w Media Center, and /w Bing, so there are now then just Windows 8, and Windows 8 Professional.  Why do I make that comment, all of those versions, cannot be installed with the others license key this are unique versions